# Запрос данных из двух таблиц и вывод через while

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Есть две таблицы comments и users. Они связаны между собой. Необходимо получить данные из обеих таблиц в одном запросе. Делаю такой запрос

```
$Result = mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'SELECT comments.id, comments.added, comments.date, comments.text, users.id, users.fname, users.lname, users.avatar, users.login FROM comments, users ORDER BY comments.id DESC');
```

И вывожу:

```
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)) { echo '
  <h6 class="comment__name">
  <a href="/users/'.$User['login'].'">'.$Row['fname'].' '.$Row['added'].' '.$Row['lname'].'</a></h6>
  <span>'.$Row['date'].'</span>
  <div class="comment__content">'.$Row['text'].'</div>
';}
```

Проблема в следующем: одну и ту же строку while выводит 2 раза.

Спасибо [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) за подсказку, решение:

```
$Result = mysqli_query($CONNECT, ('SELECT comments.id, comments.added, comments.date, comments.text, users.id, users.fname, users.lname, users.avatar, users.login FROM comments, users WHERE comments.added = users.login ORDER BY comments.id DESC'));
```

Comment: Странно что всего два. Он должен выводить все записи из первой таблицы в количестве записей из второй таблицы, потому как вы не указали в фразе where условие какие строки с какими связывать

Comment: Если таблицы не связаны, то какого пользователя рядом с каким комментарием вам надо показать ?

Comment: Того пользователя который добавил данный комментарий

Comment: А говорите, что таблицы не связаны ... Они как раз и связаны по этому признаку. Как поле с id пользователя оставившего комментарий называется в таблице comments ?

Comment: спасибо)) вверху написал решение.

Answer (score 2):

Если таблицы связаны по `id` используйте, например, такой запрос:

```
SELECT
   c.id,
   c.added,
   c.date,
   c.text,
   u.fname,
   u.lname,
   u.avatar,
   u.login
FROM 
   comments c,
   users u
WHERE c.id = u.id
ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

или используйте `join`.

Answer (score -1):

Если сам запрос возвращает по 2 строки, добавь DISTINCT после SELECT

```
SELECT DISTINCT comments.id, comments.added, comments.date, comments.text, users.id, users.fname, users.lname, users.avatar, users.login 
FROM comments, users 
ORDER BY comments.id DESC
```

Comment: Ага, разбежались. он же без условия объединения написал таблицы, будет много записей и все разные comment 1 user 1, потом comment 1 user 2 и т.п. и главное они будут хоть на одно поле, но разные и distinct не поможет

Comment: Какая разница, если сейчас выводит правильно, только задвоенно. Другое дело, что я просмотрел что часть полей выводимых в селекте не участвует в выводе, и на них дистинкт действиетльно может не сработать. Но в этом случае их можно просто убрать, ведь они не выводятся. Либо дописать "тонкости" задачи. Но для текущего описания дистинкт подходит вполне.

Comment: Это оно задвоено потому что в одной из таблиц всего 2 записи

Comment: Пусть 2, дистинкт это исправит. Я не говорю что решение с джойном не верное, оно более правильное. Но я думаю что обращаясь с таким вопросом, автор был бы рад наиболее простому решению. дистинкт проще чем джойн по какому то признаку :)

Comment: Да автор просто не понимает что у него значения не задвоены, а что в строках только последние поля различны, а задвоено только начало ... и distinct это не исправит. а join в вопросе и так присутствует, только в виде равноценного ему оператора запятая

Comment: Дистинкт исправит конечные задвоения. А то чем они вызваны это уже другая тема.

Comment: там _нет_ конечных задвоений, все строки разные, просто автор вопроса этого не замечает потому как в html печатет видимым образом только значения из первой таблицы, а из второй кладет внутрь ссылок и на экране он этого просто не видит

Comment: Про это я писал, во втором комментарии к этому посту.